# float sql server conversion issue

Tags: sql-server

i have this statement :

```
Select STORE_NAME,STORE_LATITUDE,STORE_LONGTITUDE
 from stores 
  where STORE_LATITUDE=24.6669863852163
         and STORE_LONGTITUDE=46.69189453125
```

this statement should return one row and i am pretty sure that i put the correct latitude and longitude as they are in the Database Table but it returning null value and not the store that i am looking for but i can't find my mistake STORE_LATITUDE,STORE_LONGITUDE are declared as float

Comment: Try `where STORE_LATITUDE BETWEEN 24.6669863852162 AND 24.6669863852164 and STORE_LONGTITUDE BETWEEN 46.69189453124 AND 46.69189453126`. Don't compare floats for exact equality.

Comment: Can you show output of `select top 5 STORE_LATITUDE, STORE_LONGTITUDE from stores` ?

Comment: try str(sore_laitude)=str('24.6669863852163')

Comment: Use a decimal datatype for lat/long data. It has a defined structure. This avoids the typical float problems.

Comment: @SvenSchneider i can't change the Table design

Comment: Or the geography type if on 2008+

Comment: @Sora This is a serious issue then. Perform a string conversion is possible solution but surely a performance aspect.

Comment: @SvenSchneider - If the columns are indexed then plus/minus-ing a small epsilon value and using `BETWEEN` will work fine.

Comment: So what was the problem? Did you solve?

Comment: @SvenSchneider Decimal data is totally inappropriate for lat/long data.

Comment: @OllieJones And you can confirm your statement by which arguments? WGS84 is pretty well defined so I'm looking forward to your arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Floating point values are inherently approximations. It's really hard to get them to compare equal; the old adage about "close counts in hand-grenades and horseshoes" also applies to floating point computations.

What I'm trying to say is, you can't reliably test for equality between floating point numbers, ever.

You need a query something like this:

```
 Select STORE_NAME,STORE_LATITUDE,STORE_LONGTITUDE
   from stores 
  where STORE_LATITUDE BETWEEN 24.6669863852163 - 0.0001
                           AND 24.6669863852163 + 0.0001
    AND STORE_LONGTITUDE BETWEEN 46.69189453125 - 0.0001
                             AND 46.69189453125 + 0.0001
```

By the way, 0.0001 degrees of latitude is equivalent to about 11 meters on the ground.  It's unlikely that your store locations are anywhere near that accurate, because that's where the spherical assumption for the shape of the earth starts to fall apart.

The precision of a latitude datum like 24.6669863852163 is around 11 nanometers, or the size of a molecule of complex carbohydrate or some such thing.  That's cool for molecular biology, but obviously overkill for a store finder.

Answer (score 0):

Floats don't hold the precision correctly, if you need the exact precission then you have to with the decimal data Type .
in the above case you can re-define the values as Decimal(38,20) to store the longitude and latitude values.

If you are using SQL Server 2008 or later version, SQL Server supports SPATIAL data types, which has the functionality to hold the longitudes and latitudes and also does a lot of calculations on top of them.

You can find more about the spatial data types from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933790.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try using **[cast() or convert()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)**

```
Select STORE_NAME,STORE_LATITUDE,STORE_LONGTITUDE
from stores 
where Convert(decimal(9,2),STORE_LATITUDE)=24.66
and Convert(decimal(9,2),STORE_LONGTITUDE)=46.69
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine in Sql Server 2008: [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f91cb/1)